# Change Alt-Tab icon size in mint

Tags: linux-mint, icons, alt-tab

I have linux mint 16 cinnamon.

Is it possible to change the size of icons in Alt-Tab?

Comment: Might be useful: http://worldofgnome.org/seven-alttabs-for-gnome-shell-3-6-and-counting/